# Rails downloading empty csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a problem with Downloading csv files from my rails app.

First the controller looks like this;

```
def report
  @report = SentMessage.where('user_id = ? AND created_at <= ? AND created_at >=   ?', current_user.id, params[:before], params[:after]).order('created_at Desc')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      response.headers["Content-Type"]        = "text/csv; charset=UTF-8; header=present"
      response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=sent_messages.csv"
    end
  end
end
```

then my report.csv.erb file looks like this;

```
<%= provide(:title, "Sent Messages") %>
<div>
  <div class="panel radius"> <h2 class="text_center">Sent Messages</h2></div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hoverlarge-12 radius columns large-centered" id="sent_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>To</th>
          <th>From</th>
          <th>Message</th>
          <th>Delivery Report</th>
          <th>cost</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @report.each do |message| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= message.to %></td>
              <td><%= message.from %></td>
              <td><%= message.message %></td>
              <td><%= message.delivery %></td>
              <td><%= message.cost %></td>
              <td><%= message.created_at.to_datetime.strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M%P") %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i click the download link, the downloaded file is just empty besides the headers as show in the **report.csv.erb** file.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have data in `@report`?

Comment: Not a solution but an observation: CSV stands for Comma-separated Values, but you are attempting to write HTML here.

Comment: I simply think that there are no messages.
To check the result run the query from the console and see it's response.

Comment: @thorstenmüller, yes there is data because its actually displaying on report.html.erb

Comment: I would in such a case just add something like `<% logger.info @report %>` before the part that actually generates the output and a similar log for every single line. This should show you if it even reachs this part of your code.

Comment: @thorstenmüller, you are right. `@report` is empty. why do u think so?

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to change the link to the download  from;

> 

to

```
<%= link_to "Download CSV", params.merge(format: "csv"), class: "button radius" %>
```

And it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Do like that may be work for you.

```
def report
            @report = SentMessage.where('user_id = ? AND created_at <= ? AND created_at >=   ?', current_user.id, params[:before], params[:after]).order('created_at Desc')
                  respond_to do |format|
                           format.html
                           format.csv{
          response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv; charset=UTF-8; header=present"
          response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment;                       filename=sent_messages.csv"}


                        end
  end
```

Comment: You only changed do..end to curly braces. How do you think this would make a difference?